# applying datetime format to string

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in string format:

`extractdate = '20200331'`

I want to convert this to `"31 Mar 2020"`.

I have the below so far but always get confused with the `datetime` operation:

```
(str(datetime.strptime(extractdate,'%Y%m%d').day) + " "
 + str(datetime.strptime(extractdate,'%Y%m%d').month) + " "
 + str(datetime.strptime(extractdate,'%Y%m%d').year))
```

which gives me

```
'31 3 2020'
```

How do I convert `3` to `Mar`?

Comment: Use %b, e.g. `datetime.strptime('20200331','%Y%m%d').strftime('%d %b %Y')`. Checkout https://strftime.org/, takes you less time than you need to write a question on SO ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `%B` for March or `%b` for the abbreviated Mar. You can find all the cases [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime).

```
datetime.strptime('20200331','%Y%m%d').strftime('%d %b %Y')
```